# Pandas Python- can datetime be used with vectorized inputs

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas dataframe has year, month and date in the first 3 columns. To convert them into a datetime type, i use a for loop that loops over each row taking the content in the first 3 columns of each row as inputs to the datetime function. Any way i can avoid the for loop here and get the dates as a datetime?

Comment: I had the exact same question yesterday, are you also taking the coursera course?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a vectorized hook, but you can use `apply`, anyhow:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"year": [1992, 2003, 2014], "month": [2,3,4], "day": [10,20,30]})
>>> df
   day  month  year
0   10      2  1992
1   20      3  2003
2   30      4  2014
>>> df["Date"] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.datetime(x['year'], x['month'], x['day']), axis=1)
>>> df
   day  month  year                Date
0   10      2  1992 1992-02-10 00:00:00
1   20      3  2003 2003-03-20 00:00:00
2   30      4  2014 2014-04-30 00:00:00
```