# adding a new column with values from the existing ones

Tags: pandas

what's the most pandas-appropriate way of achieving this? I want to create a column with datetime objects from the 'year','month' and 'day' columns, but all I came up with is some code that looks way too cumbersome:

```
myList=[]
for row in df_orders.iterrows():  #df_orders is the dataframe
    myList.append(dt.datetime(row[1][0],row[1][1],row[1][2]))
    #-->year, month and day are the 0th,1st and 2nd columns.
mySeries=pd.Series(myList,index=df_orders.index)
df_orders['myDateFormat']=mySeries
```

thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(yyyy=[2000, 2000, 2000, 2000], 
                               mm=[1, 2, 3, 4], day=[1, 1, 1, 1]))
```

Convert to an integer:

```
In [2]: df['date'] = df['yyyy'] * 10000 + df['mm'] * 100 + df['day']
```

Convert to a string, then a datetime (as `pd.to_datetime` will interpret the integer differently):

```
In [3]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].apply(str))

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   day  mm  yyyy                date
0    1   1  2000 2000-01-01 00:00:00
1    1   2  2000 2000-02-01 00:00:00
2    1   3  2000 2000-03-01 00:00:00
3    1   4  2000 2000-04-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: this is also another way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839360/pandas-python-can-datetime-be-used-with-vectorized-inputs