# Vectorized Operations on a datetime column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to take a column of datetime objects and return a column of integers that are "days from that datetime until today". I can do it in an ugly way, looking for a prettier (and faster) way.

So suppose I have a dataframe with a datetime column like so:

```
11    2014-03-04 17:16:26+00:00
12    2014-03-10 01:35:56+00:00
13    2014-03-15 02:35:51+00:00
14    2014-03-20 05:55:47+00:00
15    2014-03-26 04:56:33+00:00
Name: datetime, dtype: object
```

And each element looks like:

```
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 4, 17, 16, 26, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Suppose I want to calculate how many days ago each observation occurred, and return that as a simple integer. I know I can just use `apply` twice, but is there a vectorized/cleaner way to do it?

```
today = datetime.datetime.today().date()
df_dates = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
days_ago = today - df_dates
```

Which gives a timedelta64[ns] Series.

```
11   56 days, 00:00:00
12   50 days, 00:00:00
13   45 days, 00:00:00
14   40 days, 00:00:00
15   34 days, 00:00:00
Name: datetime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

And then finally if I want it as an integer:

```
days_ago_as_int = days_ago.apply(lambda x: x.item().days)
days_ago_as_int
11    56
12    50
13    45
14    40
15    34
Name: datetime, dtype: int64
```

Any thoughts?

---

Related questions that didn't quite get at what I was asking:

[Pandas Python- can datetime be used with vectorized inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839360/pandas-python-can-datetime-be-used-with-vectorized-inputs)

[Pandas add one day to column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480897/pandas-add-one-day-to-column)

---

Trying [Karl D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23378765/3393459), I'm successfully able to get today's date and the date column as desired, but something goes awry in the subtraction (different datetimes than in the original example, but shouldn't matter, right?):

```
converted_dates = df['date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
today_date = np.datetime64(dt.date.today())
print converted_dates
print today_date
print today_date - converted_dates

[2014-01-16 00:00:00 
2014-01-19 00:00:00 
2014-01-22 00:00:00
2014-01-26 00:00:00
2014-01-29 00:00:00]

2014-04-30 00:00:00

[16189 days, 0:08:20.637994
16189 days, 0:08:20.637991
16189 days, 0:08:20.637988
16189 days, 0:08:20.637984
16189 days, 0:08:20.637981]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about (for a column named date)?

```py
import datetime as dt
df['foo'] = (np.datetime64(dt.date.today()) 
             - df['date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'))
print df

                 date     foo
0 2014-03-04 17:16:26 56 days
1 2014-03-10 01:35:56 50 days
2 2014-03-15 02:35:51 45 days
3 2014-03-20 05:55:47 40 days
4 2014-03-26 04:56:33 34 days
```

Or if you wanted it as an int:

```py
df['foo'] = (np.datetime64(dt.date.today()) 
             - df['date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')).astype(int)
print df
                  date  foo
0 2014-03-04 17:16:26   56
1 2014-03-10 01:35:56   50
2 2014-03-15 02:35:51   45
3 2014-03-20 05:55:47   40
4 2014-03-26 04:56:33   34
```

Or if it was an index

```py
print np.datetime64(dt.date.today()) - df.index.values.astype('datetime64[D]')

[56 50 45 40 34]
```

**Much later Edit**: How about this for a work around?

```py
>>> print df

                 date
0 2014-03-04 17:16:26
1 2014-03-10 01:35:56
2 2014-03-15 02:35:51
3 2014-03-20 05:55:47
4 2014-03-26 04:56:33
```

Try assigning today's date to a column so it gets converted to a datetime64 column by pandas and then do the arithmetic:

```
>>> df['today'] = dt.date.today()
>>> df['foo'] = (df['today'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
               - df['date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'))
>>> print df

                 date       today     foo
0 2014-03-04 17:16:26  2014-05-14 71 days
1 2014-03-10 01:35:56  2014-05-14 65 days
2 2014-03-15 02:35:51  2014-05-14 60 days
3 2014-03-20 05:55:47  2014-05-14 55 days
4 2014-03-26 04:56:33  2014-05-14 49 days
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But it actually didn't quite work for me -- I added my attempt to follow your code in my question.

Comment: Can you check the dtype on your `converted_dates`  and `today_date`?

Comment: Ah, `converted_dates` is datetime64[D], `today_date` is 
datetime64[us]. Is there a good way to convert `today_date`?

Comment: That's the difference. When I did that it created `datetime64[D]`. I  would think: `today_date = np.datetime64(dt.date.today(),'D')`.

Comment: Hm, when I try that I get `TypeError: function takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`. I'm using NumPy 1.6.2 if that matters.

Comment: Yep, the numpy version is likely to be the culprit here. I know that datetime stuff in numpy changed a lot between 1.6 and 1.7. See here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe: `np.datetime64(dt.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))` as a workaround for numpy 1.6

Comment: Argh, that still gives me `dtype('datetime64[us]')`. I guess I'm stuck doing it in an ugly way or upgrading numpy. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: By the way... I'm now using numpy 1.8.1 and the same thing is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: You still have the `TypeError`? I don't know ... I can't reproduce it. But I added a potential workaround. Does that work?